# Plone not starting ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8

Tags: python, plone, zope, plone-4.x

I have installed Plone using unified installer.

I have tried starting plone using :

```
plone@localhost [zeocluster]# ./bin/plonectl start
zeoserver: . 
daemon process started, pid=6738
client1: . 
daemon process started, pid=6743
client2: . 
daemon process started, pid=6756
```

When I check for the status I am getting below info:

```
plone@localhost [zeocluster]# ./bin/plonectl start
zeoserver: . 
daemon process started, pid=6738
client1: . 
daemon process started, pid=6743
client2: . 
daemon process started, pid=6756
```

When I try to run the client1 in fg , getting the below response.

```
plone@localhost [zeocluster]# ./bin/client1 fg
2015-07-14 03:57:35 INFO ZServer HTTP server started at Tue Jul 14 03:57:35 2015
Hostname: 0.0.0.0
Port: 8080
2015-07-14 03:57:35 INFO Zope Set effective user to "plone_daemon"
2015-07-14 03:57:35 ERROR Application Could not import Products.ATContentTypes
.......
......
File "/usr/local/Plone/Python-2.7/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 443, in _parse_localename
raise ValueError, 'unknown locale: %s' % localename
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
```

Even I tried to find the local using :

```
plone@localhost [bin]# printenv LANG
en_US.UTF-8
```

my buildout.cfg has the below values also:

```
environment-vars =
    LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
    LANG en_US.UTF-8
```

Can someone help me out to solve the issue.

Comment: Have your tried a lowercase version? "LANG en_US.utf8"?

Comment: Can we get two or three lines of the stacktrace before the "line 443, in `_parse_localename`" line? `_parse_localename` is correct in complaining, it's expecting to see something like "en_US.UTF-8", not just "UTF-8", at that point, but I can't tell why it's not getting the full value.

Comment: @mahesh - I agree with Ulrich - more of the stacktrace is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://plone-training.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plone_training_config/instructions.html recommends the following for your error (it's for OSX & Vagrant, but I guess you might as well try it even if you've got a different setup):

> In that case you have to [set] the localized keyboard and language
>   settings in the .bash_profile of the vagrant user to your locale (e.g. en_US.UTF-8 or de_DE.UTF-8)
>
> ```
> export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
> export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
> ```

Comment: @mahesh good to hear. Were you on anything different to OSX? (just to help anyone else looking)

Comment: This fix is only correct if you speak English and live in the US (which typically isn't the case for people that see this issue). The real fix is to set `LANG` to the correct string for your locale (you can list them all with `locale -a`), generally using the one that ends with `UTF-8`.